# Manhua where the main character is a lord in a medieval time period

Tags: story-identification, manga

There was this manhua I was reading where the main character (maybe isekai) is in this medieval world with a demon servant. He is the lord of this village. The strangest part is that the demon servant sucks the blood off of the main character's finger. There are undertones of it being gay. The main character then discovers a dungeon (or it spawns) in his domain and he levels up in the dungeon.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about the main character or the demon servant? Something like what they looked like? Was the main character fat, thin, blonde, dark-haired? Was the demon servant demonic looking, human looking, ghost-like? You mention leveling up, how was that determined? Were there status windows, somewhere to go to check the levels, or just generally they can use higher level magic/skill/ect. When do you think you read this? Last week, last month, last year?